# Is the author uses another reference for this result.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

In this page:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Asymptotics_and_bounds

The author write the inequality: $$|ψ(x)-x|≤0.006409(x/log x)$$ for $x≥e²²$.

But when looking to the original source:  *Rosser, J. Barkley; Schoenfeld, Lowell (1962). "Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers". Illinois J. Math. 6: 64–94.* (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807)

I cannot find this inequality.

My **question** is: Is the author uses another reference for this result.

Comment: Wikipedia also cites Dusart's articles for this part. Did you check his papers, respectively his thesis?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: There is no inequality similar to the one given in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article cites multiple sources; the right one is:

> *Pierre Dusart*, [Sharper bounds for $\psi, \theta, \pi, p_k$](https://www.unilim.fr/laco/rapports/1998/R1998_06.pdf), Rapport de recherche no. 1998-06, Université de Limoges.

It is Theorem 3 on page 6.

Comment: It is not conditional (related to RH). Thank you.