# Bounds on the Chebyshev function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

From this page:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Asymptotics_and_bounds

I am asking if it is possible to get the inequality: $$ψ\left(x\right)<x-√x\log ²x)/8π$$ for $x≥w$ where $w$ is a finite real number.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486992/is-the-author-uses-another-reference-for-this-result).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: What is the relation between them.

Comment: The references are at the relation between them. Have you checked Dusart?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: There is no similar inequality in the Dusart thesis.

Comment: It's unlikely. The very same wiki page, [properties section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Properties) says "and infinitely many natural numbers $x$ such that"

$$\psi (x)-x>K{\sqrt  {x}}$$

Comment: @rtybase: I am asking if this theorem due to Erhard Schmidt is related to Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Did you mean $\psi(x) < x + \frac{1}{8\pi}\sqrt{x}\,(\log x)^2$? Or $\psi(x) > x - \frac{1}{8\pi}\sqrt{x}\,(\log x)^2$? [Schoenfeld](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-134/S0025-5718-1976-0457374-X/) proves that if the Riemann hypothesis holds, then the former inequality holds for $x \geqslant 73.2$ and the latter for $x \geqslant 59$. If RH is wrong, then of course both inequalities are violated for arbitrarily large $x$.